# Cogs don't work on repl.it discord.py (i used the method with flask to keep it always on)

Tags: python, replit

As said in the title it doesn't work the bot doesn't respond and no error shows up. Works on my pc

Comment: please give us more details. Any Errors? Code? Please read This: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The bot isn't working for me either. Better to just program your own, based off the code on Discord.py.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).